# Regex Match all characters between one string and the appropriate parenthese

Tags: swift, regex

How can I match the characters between "func " and the appropriate ")" including this ")".
in this image , the selected text is what I want to get.

[image]

to test:

```
func greet(person: String) -> String {
    //...
}
func fetchImages() async throws -> [UIImage] {
    //...
}
func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    //...
}

func printMathResult(_ mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int, _ a: Int, _ b: Int) {
    //...
}

func mathResult(_ mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int, anotherFunc: (Double) -> Int) -> (Int) -> Int {
    //...
}
```

Comment: What regular expression engine is this? I think you need quite a complex recursive regular expression for this. Have you considered using a reflection framework or pre-existing parser for this the programming language this is written in?

Comment: This is Swift language @Evert

Comment: Have you considered using a Swift AST parser instead of a regular expression?